# Possible to use enums to restrict values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

We can easily restrict the supported value using literal types such as below

```js
type GenderConfig = {
  gender: 1 | 0
}

const obj: GenderConfig = {
  gender: 100 // throw error because value is not 1 or 0
}
```

Now as much as possible I would like to avoid magic number `1` & `0`

so I tried to define an enum for that

```js
enum Gender {
  MALE= 1,
  FEMALE=0,
}

type GenderConfig = {
  gender: Gender
}

const obj: GenderConfig = {
  gender: 100 // This doesn't throw error anymore?
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA4qAmwBOUDeBYAUFKBZAggDICiAvFAIwA0WOAYsQSaQAw2YC+WWALgJ4AHYLATIAwgHsQAMwCWAcyjkM2KPNFIAXCJCIkWLpiwBjKQGceUCQCMAVtri7xUuYuW01G7RRYsoAen8oABUAC1kzKHgJYDMQAHJLHlCkCQB3KGRUlABDED4ICSRgAH4DIA)

Surprisingly, `gender: 100` is no longer throwing error which I don't understand the rationale behind this?

Comment: Enums have this problem in almost all languages. This is because an *enum* is just a named number, at the end of the day. So if you say that something is some kind of enum, that doesn't really prevent you using the integer directly. Or a different integer. Or an expression that resolves to an integer (unknown which one at compile time). Java makes enums a proper type, so they *are* distinct and not some integers with names. TS instead makes enums just named numbers *or* strings.

Comment: There is no reason for you to put in a number in gender when you want it to be a part of the enum. The enum only serves the purpose of a named number as @VLAZ points out. So the use of an enum would be to assign a number no matter what the value might be. So if you created a new person, then you could write: `gender: Gender.MALE` in order to make the person a man. No matter how your code handles males (what number they might be or be changed to). So enums are used to assign numbers or keep them consistent - not to restrict like in your first example.

Comment: If you do not need to be able to use 0 and 1 in legacy code, you can make the enum string values `enum Gender {MALE= "MALE",FEMALE="FEMALE"}` Not as nice, but it would force calls as `const obj: GenderConfig = {gender: Gender.MALE }` Probably not suitable for your situation, but thought I would mention it just in case \o/

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen: I understand your point but I sort of disagree. The sole purpose of TypeScript is to provide type safety feature to JS, and since `enums` is one of the features brought by them, allowing it to perform type checking is fair i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const MALE = 1;
const FEMALE = 0;

type Gender = typeof MALE | typeof FEMALE;

type GenderConfig = {
  gender: Gender
}

const obj: GenderConfig = {
  gender: 100 // This is now throwing error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgQQDIFEYF4YEYDcBYAKFElgDEVFUMYAGfAwqATwAcBTGAcTbABM2ATtWbsQAM3jI0AHxgi24mOUop6jVh259BAYXBiAlgHNqAb0IwYRnvwEAuLjcGEAvoULFoMEACMAVg5atnpghiaY5gSW1tr22DQ0MAD0STAAKgAWBhAwvCBsEGAA5LBQGQIgAO4wghVCAIZgTAC2IAJsAPyuQA)

Instead of using `enums`, I've changed it to `type` and by using the combination of `const` and `typeof`, I can avoid magic number and improve readability and consistency, thanks others for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

What you've created here is a *numeric enum*. The generated JavaScript looks like this:

```
var Gender;
(function (Gender) {
    Gender[Gender["MALE"] = 1] = "MALE";
    Gender[Gender["FEMALE"] = 0] = "FEMALE";
})(Gender || (Gender = {}));
```

In the console, this object looks like this:

```
Object
  0: "FEMALE"
  1: "MALE"
  FEMALE: 0
  MALE: 1
```

Under the hood, the enum is really just a JavaScript object with properties. It has the named properties you defined,
and they are assigned a number representing the position in the enum that they exist (FEMALE being 0, MALE being 1), but
the object also has number keys with a string value representing the named constant.

Therefore, you can pass in numbers to a function that expects an enum. The enum itself is both a number and a defined constant.

This appears to defeat the type-safe aspect of TypeScript, since you can pass an arbitrary number to a function expecting this enum.
There are two reasons why this is useful, though:

1. When you receive numeric data (say, in a JSON payload from some service), you can convert it to an enum.
2. Since the enum members have numeric values, you can also use them as bitflags (although since you can set the numeric value
   for each enum member, as you have done here, this may or may not work well).

Regarding point (1): if you declare an enum without numeric values, e.g. this:

```
enum Gender {
  MALE = "Male",
  FEMALE = "Female"
}
```

then you can no longer do this:

```
const gender: Gender = "Male";
```

You'll have to do an explicit cast:

```
const gender = "Male" as Gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use enums that much anymore because they are kind of complicated. Maybe this is possible somehow but you can use strings like this instead:

```
type Gender = 'female' | 'male';
type GenderConfig = {
  gender: Gender
}
```

Of course you may need to add some mapping if you really need the number representation at some point.